# Why the CSS hover effect is not working?

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://dgprint.dg-site.com/)

If you click on "products", will open a submenu. I want to add a hover effect to this submenu .

I tried this code but do not understand why not go? I missed something?

```
.sub-menu li:hover{color:red'}
```

It certainly is probably something simple but I can't realize where is the problem.

You can help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of the submenu items is controlled by

```
#menu-main-menu .sub-menu li a {
    color: #ddd;
}
```

so you would need

```
#menu-main-menu .sub-menu li a:hover {
    color: red; /* or whatever color you wish */
}
```